# batch file to run mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I wrote a sql script to create a clean database (one.sql), I did this on CMD and it works,

```
cd MYSQL\path1\bin
mysql -u userID -ppassword -h host -P port < path2\one.sql > path2\test.log
```

it gives me the test.log file and database on the sql server was updated

And I tried to do the same thing using batch file,

```
@echo off
c:
cd "MYSQL\path1\bin"
mysql -u userID -ppassword -h host -P port < path2\one.sql > path2\test.log
pause
```

from the CMD prompt, it seems working, but no test.log file generated, and the new database in my sql server was not created.

I ran bat file by double clicking it in its folder.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: So you realize it is trying to read the SQL file and write to the log file from this path: `C:\MYSQL\path1\bin\path2`

Comment: My understanding is that, it runs one.sql and output a log file to path2 and path2 and C:\MYSQL\path1\bin\ are different.

path2 is outside C:\MYSQL\path1\bin\, I do have a full path like this
C:\Users\AAA\BBB\VVV\CCC\DDD\

Comment: You are using a relative path in your script.  The working directory for your script is `C:\MYSQL\path1\bin`.  So if you need the script to read and write to a different directory you need to provide the full path to that directory in your script.